# Reading a very large single HDF file with Dask whith sorted_index=True

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

I have a large.h5 file containing a pandas dataframe, and it is too large to fit into RAM. I expected `chunksize` to be helpfull, but whatever its values `npartitions` is always equal to 1 whenever sorted_index=True (ie when I know in advance that the index is already sorted).

```
import dask.dataframe as dd    
df = dd.read_hdf('large.h5', key='data', chunksize=10000, mode='r', sorted_index=True)
```

So that when I run:

```
df.mean().compute()
```

A single partition is made and my RAM quickly saturated.

Weirdly,

```
import dask.dataframe as dd    
df = dd.read_hdf('large.h5', key='data', chunksize=10000, mode='r', sorted_index=False)
```

Works perfectly ...

Comment: If you think that you have found a bug then I recommend making an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and submitting a bug report: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/new

Comment: Is it a bug or the intended behaviour ?

Comment: Personally I don't know